How to bind SAP UI5 Model response with the handler function
I have a function which creates an entry in backend when the save button is pressed.
Code for creating entry:
var oModel = this.getModel('action');
oModel.create(path, body, {
  success: this._onSuccess.bind(this),   //How to pass response along with the bind function
  error: this._onError.bind(this)
});
_onSuccess: function (response) {
  // Response is not having any headers
  //Show some success message
},

Instead of directly calling the function, I have bound the _onSuccess function to oModel.create success handler. From the backend I am sending some header parameters along the (POST) response, which I need to access inside the _onSuccess message and display.
When I directly include the function in success handler, I am able to see the response, but how to send it along the bind parameter?
This is working:
callCreate: function (path, body) {
  var oModel = this.getModel('action');
  oModel.create(path, body, {
    success: function (data, response) {
        //I am able to get the response headers here
    },
    error: this._onError.bind(this)
  });
},


I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do? Are you able to retrieve the headers in response to the request and would you like to insert them into a new model? Could you explain a little more?

I am also not understanding what you are trying to achieve.  If what you want is to display that new record in a table/list, then in the success function just do a refresh of the model bound to that table/list
